# Oracle 11, 12 difference in retrieving data

Tags: oracle11g, oracle12c

we are receiving data from oracle 11 version into UI but the data is not retrieved when we are using Oracle 12, can any one let me know the solution?

Comment: What you have asked is the equivalent of "My old car starts, but my new car doesn't start. Why not?" There isn't anywhere near enough information in your question for us to be able to help you. We have no sample data, no clue what your code is, etc. Please take some time to edit your question to provide a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem - remember we don't have access to your computer, architecture, data, etc. You're going to need to be much more explicit in your question to enable us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Could be virtually *anything*. For example:

- tables in 12c version are empty
- `WHERE` clause you use prevents query from returning anything
- there's a virtual private database which won't allow you to fetch data
- if you use a database link, it points to a database which is different from the one you *think* you are accessing
- connect string is wrong; or, the database name (alias) you entered is wrongly set in the TNSNAMES.ORA file

I'm pretty sure that other site members know some more reasons. Meanwhile, what's written above might give you some ideas.